# activate constraints in uitableviewcell not working first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have following hierarchy in UITableViewCell.

```
UITableViewCell
-UIView1
--UILabel1
-UIView2
--UILabel2
```

I want UIView1 to be hidden by height when UILabel1 have no text. For that I have taken a height constraint of 0 for UIView1 with initially uninstalled state.

Now in cellForRowAtIndexPath I am activating this constraint when i check the string for Label1 is empty or not?

This is not working for the first load of the cell and when i scroll through the tableview this constraint is applied. I am using [cell layoutIfNeeded] after activating constraints but it seems not to be working here for first load.

How can i crack this issue?

Comment: Please post your code for 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'.

Comment: If u can share demo project or code, people can help you easily

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by creating two constraints and changing their priorities in runtime.

The constraint priority happens in `layoutSubviews()` of subclassed UITableViewCell.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

quite late but maybe it will help someone:

Like above, you just need to override layoutSubviews function

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    //update your constraints
    //NOTE: there's no need to call layoutIfNeeded 
}
```

Comment: Made some progress but height is still not changed.

Answer (score 0):

add 2 constraints with same priority of 1000 according to your requirement and then remove them in the interface builder, make their outlets and according to your requirement make them **active** in the code and don't forget to use **layoutIfNeeded**

Comment: Works only starting iOS 13 for me